# How can i display an enum without all informations

Tags: java, arrays, enums, option-type

Hello i have a Planet class like below and i want to display Enum like MERCURY EARTH Etc ... without the informations between parenthesis and i'm using the CommonName inside the parenthesis like MERCURE , TERRE to search and display the Enum

```
public  enum Planet {

    MERCURY(0.387,"MERCURE") , VENUS(0.722,"VÉNUS"), EARTH(1.0,"TERRE"), MARS(1.52,"MARS"), JUPITER(5.20,"JUPITER"),
    SATURN(9.58,"SATURNE"),  URANUS(19.2,"URANUS"),  NEPTUNE(30.1,"NEPTUNE");
    private double  distance;
    private String commonName;
    




    
    private Planet(double v, String c) {
        distance = v;
        commonName = c;
    }

    public  double getDistanceFromTheSunInAstronomicalUnit(double distance) {
        return distance;
    }


    public  String getCommonName() {
        return commonName;
    }

    @Override //
    public  String toString() {
        return ""+commonName+ " ("+distance+")";
    }
}
```

And i have this function

```
 Optional <Planet> Dept = Arrays.stream(Planet.values())
                        .filter(e -> e.getCommonName().equals(Dep))
                        .findFirst();

                System.out.println(Dept.get());
```

i'm trying to display the Enum without the informations between the parenthesis and comparing the CommonName with an input(Dept) but the problem is everytime i get the informations inside the parenthesis

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: What do you mean by you get information inside parenthesis?

Comment: MERCURY **(0.387,"MERCURE")** This one in bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search value like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional <Planet> Dept = Arrays.stream(Planet.values())
            .filter(e -> e.name()==Planet.MERCURY.name())
            .findFirst();

    System.out.println(Dept.get());
}
```

**Or Like This:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valueYouSearch="MERCURY";
    Optional <Planet> Dept = Arrays.stream(Planet.values())
            .filter(e -> e==Planet.valueOf(valueYouSearch))
            .findFirst();

    System.out.println(Dept.get());
}
```

Comment: Your solutions are really weird, as they add entirely obsolete search operations around expressions already doing the entire job. Instead of `Optional <Planet> Dept = Arrays.stream(Planet.values()) .filter(e -> e.name()==Planet.MERCURY.name()) .findFirst();`, you can simply use the already contained `Planet.MERCURY`, i.e. `Planet Dept = Planet.MERCURY;`. Likewise, `Arrays.stream(Planet.values()) .filter(e -> e==Planet.valueOf(valueYouSearch)) .findFirst();` contains `Planet.valueOf(valueYouSearch)` which does already the entire job, i.e. `Planet Dept = Planet.valueOf(valueYouSearch);`

Answer (score 3):

When printing the enum value directly, as you have found it prints information along with it. If you just want the name of the enum, e.g. "MARS", try using the `name` method, which returns a string of name.

Example: `System.out.println(Dept.get().name());`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Planet Dept = 
Arrays.stream(Planet.values())
.filter(e -> e.getCommonName().equals(Dep))
.findFirst().get();

 System.out.println(Dept);
```